# If else statement for array

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm currently hand coding my if else statement

```
if ($user_location[0] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[0];
    } else if ($user_location[1] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[1];
    } else if ($user_location[2] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[2];
    } else if ($user_location[3] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[3];
    } else if ($user_location[4] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[4];
    } else if ($user_location[5] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[5];
    } else if ($user_location[6] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[6];
    } else if ($user_location[7] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[7];
    } else if ($user_location[8] == $location){
        $user_id = $page[8];
    } else {
        $user_id = $user_gen;
    }
```

How do I make this if statement that auto increment the `$user_location[]` and `$page[]` instead of hand coding?

Comment: You could use a loop over the index of `$user_location`. I assume the language you are using supports a `for` or `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I assume you are using PHP as per you tag your question in PHP

```
$flag = true;
foreach($user_location as $index=>$each){
    if ($each == $location){
        $flag = false;
        $user_id = $page[$index];
    }
}
if ($flag){
    $user_id = $user_gen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$user_id = $user_gen;
foreach($user_location as $key => $ulocation) {
    if ($ulocation == $location) {
        $user_id = $page[$key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to initialise `$user_id` to `$user_gen` and remove the `else` statement so it doen't reassign `$user_id` with the same value everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
$user_id = $user_gen;
foreach($user_location as $key => $value){
    if($value == $location){
        $user_id = $page[$key];
        $location_find = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you flip the array and then search directly?

```
$flipped = array_flip($user_location);
$user_id = isset($flipped[$location]) ? $page[$flipped[$location]] : $user_gen;
```

If the array is flipped, you can see what key `$location` represents and use that as the index on $page. If it's not set, it'll default to $user_gen as above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for my code. But thanks anyway for this. I already use one of the other answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for this:

```
$user_id = $user_gen;
$user_id_index = array_search($location, $user_location);
if (false !== $user_id_index) {
    $user_id = $page[$user_id_index];
}
```